# Python Class not accepting argument

Tags: python, class, arguments, typeerror

I was building an ETL, taking data from different tables from a PostgreSQL database, the name of these tables where given by the name followed by "_data" and then cached using the same name. So in order to optimize my code I thought I could instanciate the class passing a list with the names. This way:

```
#Define name of clients for whom service will be run 
client_list = ['foo', 'bar', 'foofoo', 'barbar']

actuations_obj = Actuations(client_list)
```

In the file where Actuations is, it is defined this way:

```
class Actuations:

    def __init__(self, clients):
        self.clients = clients
```

When the process gets to this point, the terminal says:

TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'clients'

I already tried passing the argument as a keyword argument and then, to make it work, I defined a default value, but this hardcoded way doesn't suit my needs.
I need the class constructor to accept the same list defined in app.py, because I'm also using that list to instantiate another class.

Comment: I don't think you are using the implementation of `Actuations` you think you are.

Comment: The code you've provided (if one arranges it in the way one would expect) does not raise this error. Please **always** create and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

In actuations_obj you give only one value, while in the constructor of actuations you define two required parameters.

Based on your question what you seem to want is an optional parameter with a default value when not defined.

To me the only known way to do that in python by defining the default value in the parameter.(reference 1)

A problem with applying that method to the code you provided is that the optional parameter is at the left.

Due to it being at the start the optional parameter is defined at the same place as the value the interpreter will first read.

This causes the interpreter to always first try to define the optional parameter before it defines something else.

This can be fixed in two ways.
Reorder the parameters, so the parameters follow the order of the interperter
like this:

```
class Actuations:

def __init__(clients, self="foo"):
    self.clients = clients
```

or
define for every time you call the class without the optional paramater which parameter is what value refers to what parameter.

Like this:

```
#Define name of clients for whom service will be run 
client_list = ['foo', 'bar', 'foofoo', 'barbar']

actuations_obj = Actuations(clients = client_list)
```

reference: [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-pass-optional-parameters-to-a-function-in-python][1]

Comment: class Actuations:

def __init__(clients, self="foo"):
    self.clients = clients

I think might take the first parameter "clients" as self. Because is the init from a class constructor